# Hyper-V: Ubuntu guests running out of memory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, hyper-v, ubuntu-12.04

We appear to have a problem with Ubuntu guests running out of memory. We have several on 12.04 (LTS) and one on 13.04 and seem to have the same problem.

It takes around 30 days from restart to running out of memory.

It is likely that the problem lies with the Integration Services, when Ubuntu is run on bare metal (apparently) it can go for years without being rebooted.

Is there a solution?

Should we reboot Linux (Ubuntu) VM's regularly?

Comment: Are you able to see what is causing the memory to be used up? Is the console unresponsive at this time? What makes you think that it is the integration services? Ideally you should provide a bit more information to allow people to help you.

Comment: There's nothing magical about Ubuntu *or any other operating system* that means it will always run for 'years' on bare metal without suffering from memory leaks or other bugs. Having said that it could be a problem with integration services, or it could be just about anything else so this needs to be investigated from the ground up, I'm afraid. For a start, what are the guests actually doing?

Comment: @John, I will provide more info when the next VM runs out of memory. I was in the gym when I got the uptimerobot message, and all I could do using my iPhone was to hard-stop the VM and start it (we had to get it up right away).

Comment: I suspect integration services based on the opinion of a friend, based on the experience of his company. The VM is a LAMP server running WordPress. Pretty vanilla installation. It's also running something called eHour (which is usually the first to go down). We have other Ubuntu VMs running Rails and Apache with MySQL.

Comment: Any os can go for years without a reboot, its typically applications/services that will take you down and or virus since things haven't been patched.. look in the application services\microsoft\hyper-v-intergration event logs do you see anything abnormal there?

Comment: Here are some of the eror messages in kern.log at the time it ran out of memory:
Aug 13 07:54:42 lamp02 kernel: [1985312.498686] Out of memory: Kill process 6370 (apache2) score 12 or sacrifice child
Aug 13 07:54:42 lamp02 kernel: [1985312.501647] Killed process 6370 (apache2) total-vm:257000kB, anon-rss:9208kB, file-rss:136kB
Aug 13 07:55:08 lamp02 kernel: [1985339.675158] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Aug 13 07:55:08 lamp02 kernel: [1985339.675165] apache2 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0

Comment: Are you using dynamic RAM? I'd be curious to see if the issue persists without it.

Comment: No, we're not using Dynamic RAM. The guest has 2048MB of "static?" RAM.

Comment: Tony, where would I find the services\microsoft\hyper-v-intergration event logs? I've looked around (and Googled it) and can't find where Hyper-V IS logs are.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. We use dynamic ram. Interestingly enough, this doesn't happen with my linux servers that run mysql, only those that run a LAMP or LNMP stack. I'm wondering if it's PHP that's causing the memory to leak.